# Writing to a specific memory location

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, permissions, io

I am trying to edit a file inside `/proc/devices`-tree to be exact,
and i am unable to do so, I am getting:

> "permission denied" or "Input/Output error".

I have tried all possible combinations of editors, `chown`, `chmod` and even `sudo dd`. I also know the exact memory location to write to `7000c400` in hex. I need to replace 4 bytes there, is there any method which may help me achieve this.

Edit: **What i am trying to achieve by attempting this?**

- I have a *Jetson-TK1* board, and an *i2c* bus is set to a default of `400kHz`, but i want to run it at `100kHz`. I think i can do that by changing device tree structure and recompilation, but recompilation is a lot bigger headache, as the kernel i am using is not a standard one (nvidia doesn't provide that).

  I had read somewhere that in Linux almost everything is in the form of a file. So looking for it, i found a file which contains 4 bytes which evaluates to `400000`, I think changing this file would change the frequency.
- Now the real problem is i was unable to change it (i think i am a decent enough user and as far as i understand, if there is something in memory and i have all kinds of passwords, i should be able to change it. That fact that i mess up something is not the question). I tried all possible methods known to me (as i have added in the question). So how do i do that.

Comment: What would you do?

Comment: I did not understand your query?

Comment: That what is the thing that do you want to do.

Comment: I need to replace 4 bytes at that location. It will change the speed of i2c bus

Comment: IIRC, /proc/device-tree is simply a read-only data structure used to enumerate information regarding system hardware, so I'm not quite sure what you mean by saying you want to "edit a file inside [it]." Also, was your kernel compiled with CONFIG_PROC_DEVICETREE=Y? If you want to change the speed of an i2c bus on your device, you might want to instead look at the appropriate sysfs control inode.

Comment: @Rishabh: I can't help you, but I open a bounty. When you find useful a answer, say here and I'll assign the bounty th the answer.

Comment: Whatever sits in kernel space is not accessible from user programs, unless one would use some DMA techniques like editing `/dev/mem`. Not sure if `mmap()` could do the trick either, I believe it should. The more "elegant" way tough would be to edit the proc file directly from kernel space (i.e. from a kernel module) using the appropriate functions in `proc_fs.h`. I'll try to write a program to do that using one of these methods, hopefully I'll be able to work something out!

Comment: @Sneetsher: i will add what exactly i am trying to achieve.

Comment: @kos: if you could add some link to a tutorial or give me an example program, that would help me a lot. Thanks :)

Comment: @joshumax: As far as i understand anything can be edited, the question is not how i change bus speed, but how to edit a file (which normally isn't editable), if there is some flaw in my reasoning, please point it out. Its good to learn something new everyday

Comment: @Rishabh 1st comment: The problem is there's no tutorial around, the concept is to create a custom kernel module that upon user request would switch a proc file with another one. As of now I'm at halfway because I've managed to handle the proc file switch in the kernel module (thanks to google), but I don't know how i could pass informations about the data to handle from an userspace program. Once found out this, I'm done

Comment: @Rishabh 2nd comment: There's no flaw, it's a legit question. The memory is divided into two big sections: user space and kernel space. Directly accessing kernel space from user space could be really dangerous, so it's not allowed. The opposite instead it's allowed but still it's not suggested. That's why you need to write a custom program using kernel API for that. To answer your question, it's the intended behavior that you cannot easily/mistakenly edit those files unless you really know what you're doing

Comment: @kos, you can prepare an `linux/ioctl.h` interface in the kernel. Then use `fcntl.h` from user space to communicate with the kernel module. [See Talking to Device Files (writes and IOCTLs)](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x892.html)

Comment: @Rishabh Anyway if you want to look into this yourself you can check [this](http://tuxthink.blogspot.it/2011/02/creating-readwrite-proc-entry.html?m=1), it's the only updated source i found on the topic (kernel > 3.10), there are other sources that you can find which are still good but deprecated, they won't compile on modern kernels

Comment: @Sneetsher That's a great suggestion. Looking into this!

Comment: ¿Can you post the output of `lsmod`?

Comment: The device tree simply tells the kernel information about ARM hardware.  It is provided by the bios and is read only.  Even if you could change it, that wouldn't actually change the hardware -- only what the kernel *knows* about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into this mostly for fun and for learning (and hopefully for the rep!). I wish I could have some more time to play with `ioctl` (thanks to Sneetsher for the suggestion) and with what I've done so far in order to make a more elegant solution, but the bounty is about to expire and it's not likely that I can make everything in time, so I'm posting this solution "as it is" (at least for now).

## Disclaimer:

**I don't know which are the consequences of changing something into `/proc/device-tree`, so if you really know what you're doing, keep reading.**

This particular implementation of this solution requires a running kernel > 3.10. It involves the compilation of a custom kernel module and the execution of a `bash` script to perform a sort of hot-switch between `/proc/device-tree` and a custom file `device-tree_new`.

**Limits**:

1. Upon module removal, the custom `/proc/device-tree` it's removed! **Another reason to read the disclaimer again**.
2. The custom `/proc/device-tree`'s buffer has a limit of `65535` characters. Everything over the `65535` character is truncated. To adjust the buffer's size, change the following constant definition and variable declaration in the module's source code:

   1. `#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 65535`
   2. `static unsigned int proc_buffer_length_v;` (so that it can hold a number > `65535`)

### How it works:

The module itself:

- **deletes** `/proc/device-tree`
- **creates** a new blank `/proc/device-tree` with permissions `0666`

The `bash` script itself:

1. Loads the module
2. Writes into `/proc/device-tree` the content of `device-tree_new`

This is the "`Makefile`" `Makefile` for the module (**note that all the whitespaces at the beginning of each `make` line must be replaced with a `TAB` character**):

```
obj-m += proc_module.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

This is the "`proc_module.c`" source file of the module:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>

#define DEBUG 1
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 65535

static struct proc_dir_entry* proc_dir_entry_p;
static struct file_operations file_operations_s;
static char* proc_buffer_p;
static unsigned int proc_buffer_length_v;
static unsigned short int read_flag;

int read_proc(struct file* file, char* buffer, size_t count, loff_t* offset) {
    if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "read_proc() called.\n");
    if(read_flag)
        read_flag = 0;
    else {
        read_flag = 1;
        return 0;
    }
    copy_to_user(buffer, proc_buffer_p, proc_buffer_length_v);
    if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "Ok. (count = %zu)\n", count);
    return proc_buffer_length_v;
}

int write_proc(struct file* file, char* buffer, size_t count, loff_t* offset) {
    size_t n;
    if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "write_proc() called.\n");
    if(count >= MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
        if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "write_proc(): Buffer exceeded!\n");
        n = MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;
    }
    else
        n = count;
    kfree(proc_buffer_p);
    if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "kfree() called.\n");
    if(!(proc_buffer_p = (char*)kmalloc(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE*sizeof(char), GFP_KERNEL))) {
        if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "kmalloc() ko.\n");
        return count;
    }
    if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "kmalloc() ok.\n");
    copy_from_user(proc_buffer_p, buffer, n);
    proc_buffer_length_v = n;
    if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "Ok. (count = %zu)\n", count);
    return count;
}

static int __init init_f(void) {
    if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "Module inserted.\n");
    remove_proc_entry("device-tree", NULL);
    if(!(proc_dir_entry_p = proc_create("device-tree", 0666, NULL, &file_operations_s))) {
        if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "Proc entry not created.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "Proc entry created.\n");
    file_operations_s.read = read_proc;
    file_operations_s.write = write_proc;
    if(!(proc_buffer_p = (char*)kmalloc(1*sizeof(char), GFP_KERNEL))) {
        if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "kmalloc() ko.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "kmalloc() ok.\n");
    proc_buffer_p[0] = '\0';
    proc_buffer_length_v = 0;
    read_flag = 1;
    if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "Ok.\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit exit_f(void) {
    kfree(proc_buffer_p);
    if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "kfree() called.\n");
    proc_remove(proc_dir_entry_p);
    if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "Proc entry removal requested.\n");
    if(DEBUG) printk(KERN_INFO "Module removed.\n");
}

module_init(init_f);
module_exit(exit_f);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("kos");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("proc_module");
```

This is the "`switch.sh`" `bash` script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

sudo rmmod proc_module.ko
sudo insmod proc_module.ko && cat device-tree_new > /proc/device-tree
```

### Instructions:

1. Open a `Terminal` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. Create a new folder: `mkdir <folder_name>`
3. Change the current working directory to the new folder: `cd <folder_name>`
4. Create the three files above using the exact same names enclosed between the double-quotes
5. Create the custom `device-tree` file and name it `device-tree_new`
6. Mark "`switch.sh`" as executable: `chmod a+x switch.sh`
7. Compile the module: `make` (two warnings will be thrown by `gcc`)
8. Launch the `bash` script: `./switch.sh`
9. `cat /proc/device-tree` to see the result

Comment: You are writing to a file name /proc/device-tree, but you don't modify the purpose of the original /proc/device-tree... You answer the question but don't resolve the problem.

Comment: @Nimlar It might be, as I said i don't know which role the `device-tree` file plays exactly, so can you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 3):

`/proc/` is a pseudo file system: when you read/write on any `/proc/file` you don't access a real file or real memory, but you call some specific kernel function (depending of the file) that acts as a file. It returns data if you read the file, set data if you write to the file. And if there is no write function defined for a specific file, writing to the file won't change anything.

In this case the `/proc/device-tree` is a way to read the device tree provided to the 
running kernel while its boot. (no write enable)

Moreover, currently, the device tree is a read-only configuration, you cannot update it after the boot. 
And for your specific case, the values configuring your `i2c` are read and used when the `i2c` is probed ('installed').
If you want to reconfigure `i2c`, you need as said joshumax, to use the correct `ioctl` on the `i2c` device (in `/dev/` where some specific "driver entry" are defined)

One other solution is to build a new device tree, configuring the `I2C` device as you want. And ask the kernel (check the bootloader you are using) to use the device tree you just compiled.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need rootly powers use sudo for that. 
Try this: you can use gdb (GNU Debugger) running as root to manipulate contents of memory.
These may interest you:

http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305164/how-to-modify-memory-contents-using-gdb

Comment: `malloc()` is not useful. `malloc()` is used to allocate memory in userspace, while what the user wants is to write something already in kernel space. He'll rather have to make a clever use of `mmap()`.

Comment: Yea, i think that is right.